# i have summ difficult to run $apply

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

i have list of element when i click in one of them, i fill the template then i copy it to the new DIV, i got an empty template, when i use `$scope.$apply()` i got an error.

```
$scope.tache_list.forEach(element => {
  $scope.var1 = element;  
  $scope.$apply();
  $('#div2').append($("#div1").html());  
});
```

i got `Error $rootScope:inprog` , what i can do ?

[image: Error rootScope]

Comment: please be aware of calling the `$scope.$apply()` yourself check this link https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog

Comment: This kind of DOM manipulation inside AngularJS is not wise. Why are you using `$scope.$apply();`? Are you trying to fix some other problem like the appended code not working?

Comment: there is **A LOT** wrong with this code.  First, if you are finding yourself needing `$scope.$apply()`, you are probably doing something wrong.  Second, you seem to be mixing JQuery with Angular, which doesn't work well, and probably what is leading to you thinking you need to use `$apply()`.  Third, it's not really clear what is in `#div2` or `#div1`, or how they relate to the `element` you are trying to manipulate, but if you are trying to use `#div1` as a placeholder for `var1` so that you can use it in the JQuery call, that will never work, and isn't proper Angular at all.

Comment: you might consider posting examples of the data you are working with and the result you are trying to achieve, so we can help you write a proper algorithm that is Angularjs friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your $scope.$apply call inside a $timeout function.

```
$timeout(function(){
   $scope.$apply()
});
```

Reason: Digest cycle will be moved to event loop and execute when the existing cycle completes.

Comment: while this probably works, the code in question is a complete mess and should never need `$scope.$apply()` in the first place.

Comment: The use of `$timeout $scope.$apply` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. Care should be taken to investigate why the OP thinks this necessary.

Comment: I agree. The first aim should be,to write the code in angularjs context. The above mentioned solution is just a workaround. We should avoid using digest cycle manually.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following [article](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) about $digest and $apply

Your `inprogress` error is because you call `$apply()` from inside an `$apply block`. You only want to call the $apply from `outside` angular code that starts a new turn. So if you have a `setTimeout()` in your forEach you can call $apply inside the setTimeout to tell angular you want it to update.

Comment: The use of `setTimeout $scope.$apply` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. Care should be taken to investigate why the OP thinks this necessary.

Comment: @georgeawg i'm not saying he needs to call the `setTimeout` because you then want to use the `$timeout` which wraps `$apply` around the calls, i was just pointing out that if you use have a turn that is `outsde angular` and your setting $scope variables that you need to call $apply yourself or wrap the code in an $apply block. I'm also not understanding why the OP is using a $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 0):

i resovle this probleme by

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.$apply()
})
.then(function(){
  ...
});
```

thanks for all.